# Defining sets as countable and infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Which of the following sets are finite? countably infinite? uncountable? (Be careful -- don't apply theorems for finite sets to infinite sets and don't apply theorems for countable sets to uncountable sets!) Give reasons for your answers for each of the following:

(a) $\{1/n: n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{ 0 \} \}$;

(b) $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$

(c) $\{x \in \mathbb{N}: \lvert x-7\rvert > \lvert x \rvert \}$;

(d) $2\mathbb{Z} \times 3 \mathbb{Z}$

For (a), I think this set=$\mathbb{Q}$ which we know to be countably infinite?
(b) is infinite, but I'm not sure how to tell if it is countable.
(c) I want to say is countably infinite just by thinking about the set.
(d) Seems countably infinite as well since $\mathbb{Z}$ is countably infinite?

Comment: For some reason there were too many dollar signs in your LaTeX code (that I have edited), most of them instead of blank spaces. If you want to insert LaTeX formulae, just insert them between two matching dollar signs at the ends, not more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a): this is not $\mathbb{Q}$, since it only consists of fractions having numerator $1$, not of *all* fractions. Ans yes, this is countable, since it is in bijection with $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, which itself is countable.

(b): clearly not countable. If it had been countable, since $\mathbb{N}$ is also countable and the union of 2 countable sets is countable, then $\mathbb{N} \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}) = \mathbb{R}$ would also be countable, which is false.

(c): if $x \geq 7$, then the inequality becomes $x-7 > x$, which cannot have any solution. Therefore, it may consist of *at most* $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, which is a finite set. (In fact, it consists only of $\{0,1,2,3\}$.)

(d): correct; the product of 2 countable sets is itself countable.